# Убирается выпадающий список при попытке увода курсора с кнопки

Tags: html, css, html5

В навбаре сделал выпадающий список с помощью кода:

```css
.nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav ul ul li {
  min-width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-menu a {
  background-image: linear-gradient(currentColor, currentColor);
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 1px;
  transition: background-size .3s, color .3s;
}

.navbar-menu a:hover {
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="navbar-menu">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Useful Materials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tools_list">Tools</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#search-subdomains">Search subdomains</a></li>
        <li><a href="#http-request">HTTP Request</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sqli">SQL Injection</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке перевода курсора мыши с кнопки Tools на выпадающий вниз список, список пропадает. Как исправить?

Comment: Есть просвет между li и дочерним ul. В примере выпадающий улетает далеко вниз изза того что .nav ul ul li { position: relative } срабатывает только на li второго уровня (Search subdomains, HTTP Request, SQL Injection). а для ul с абсолютным позиционированием надо родителя c relative. Нужен position: relative для просто .nav li

Comment: Лучше использовать JS для таких вещей. CSS тоже вполне способе на это, но JS грамотнее и лучше, заморочек меньше

Comment: для таких вещей никогда не пользуйся js.  тут достаточно css, не засирай лучше код лишним js

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: fit-content;
}

.parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.parent:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.child {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: none;
  width: max-content;
}

.child li {
  width: 100%;
}

ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar-menu a {
  background-image: linear-gradient(currentColor, currentColor);
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 1px;
  transition: background-size 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.navbar-menu a:hover {
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="navbar-menu">
      <li class="parent"><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="#1">11111111111</a></li>
          <li><a href="#2">22222222222</a></li>
          <li><a href="#3">33333333333</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="#4">44444444444</a></li>
          <li><a href="#5">55555555555</a></li>
          <li><a href="#6">66666666666</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="#">Useful Materials</a>
        <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="#7">777777777777</a></li>
          <li><a href="#8">888888888888</a></li>
          <li><a href="#9">999999999999</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="#">History</a>
        <ul class="child">
          <li><a href="#search-subdomains">Search subdomains</a></li>
          <li><a href="#http-request">HTTP Request</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sqli">SQL Injection</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вариант не рабочий, подменю всегда появится в конце, даже если сделать дочерним от хистори

Comment: "Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке перевода курсора мыши с кнопки Tools на выпадающий вниз список, список пропадает. "
Эта проблема в коде и решается )
Тебе нужно полностью рабочий список написать?

Comment: дак это полностью не рабочий список, добавь подменю ещё в какой-нибудь пункт в пример, и сам всё увидишь

Comment: а потом ```.nav {
  position: relative;
}``` исправь на ```.nav li {
  position: relative;
}``` и посмотри что я пытаюсь сказать

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon поправил код выше